# Docker - SQL service wont run when cloned

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm trying to add a volume to a docker container but when I commit it and run with the new volume none of the sql services run on this copy?? Why would that be.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-powershell

I am adding the initial one as above and it works.All fine. Services running. I can connect to it, run SQL but I need to share a drive.
Seems I cant add one directly to an existing instance??

```
docker commit 5a8f89adeead newimagename
docker run -ti -v "C:/dir1":/dir1 newimagename /bin/bash
```

I do the above to clone it and add a volume. WORKS. But the sql services just arent running on this new one. Ill accept it either way I just want SQL running and a share in there.

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

Manged it:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Pa55word1" `
    -v C:/db:/dir1 `
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql3 `
   -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU3-ubuntu-18.04
```

Had an issue with having no drive or no services but this has done it.